# redis: get key-value from another computer

Tags: redis, ip, redis-cli

Computer B wants  key-value from computer A.
Redis-server is on computer A with ip address `192.16.0.2`, port `6379`.
Computer B with ip address `192.16.0.3` tries to get data from computer A.
I tried

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.0.2 -h 6379.
```

But there is no response.
To check connection, `ping 192.168.0.2` gets response within 1msec.
However `telnet 192.168.0.2 6379` does not get response.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Paste some program setup info and debugging info.. that might help others to look with you at the problem.

Comment: There appears to be a block in the route between A and B on that port... is there a firewall there?

Comment: telnet with redis?  maybe you should try ssh

Comment: Is "-h 6379" just a typo in question, or it is the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the wrong flag to specify the port.

Try using the -p flag for the port:

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.0.2 -p 6379
```

Comment: Looks like that's just a typo in question. Otherwise, OP will get error message such as "Could not connect to Redis at 6379:6379: Can't create socket: No route to host", not "there is no response"